# Mesa - glCopyPixels is much slower on iris compared to i965

Tags: opengl, gpu, intel, mesa

I'm working on a 3D application based on Blender 2.79 (which includes the old game engine), running on linux. Some more details about the system:

```
$ lsb_release -a | grep Description
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
$ uname -r
5.15.0-46-lowlatency
$ lscpu | grep Intel
Model name:                    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8665U CPU @ 1.90GHz
```

The application doesn't have much special about it except that it needs to copy every frame into memory. For this `bge.texture.ImageTexture::refresh` is used with its `buffer` parameter ([see blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bge.texture.html#bge.texture.ImageFFmpeg.refresh)).

The problem I've been seeing is that the time spent in the `refresh` call is highly varied depending on whether I use `i965` or `iris` as the driver. On the newer one, `iris`, I'm not capable of maintaining 60fps. I use the `MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE={i965,iris}` environment variable.

This is not an issue on my current hardware, but I know that i965 does not work on newer hardware, in particular 12th gen intel CPUs.

I've produced some flame graphs when running each of those drivers. Here are the important (in my opinion) bits:

*i965 (fast)*

[image: i965]

*iris (slow)*

[image: iris]

It looks like with `i965`, after `_mesa_ReadPixelsARB`, the code jumps into the intel-specific part of mesa, while with `iris` it uses something called the `state-tracker`. I suppose this is a module that bridges mesa and Gallium3D, but I'm not confident that this information is helpful.

I also attached a debugger to the `blender` process to find that the `_st_ReadPixels` seems to enter the "slow" path, according to the author ([see source](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/blob/main/src/mesa/state_tracker/st_cb_readpixels.c#L513))

At this point I would greatly appreciate someone more proficient at mesa and opengl to have a look at the information I have and help make sense of it.

Comment: `__memcpy_avx_unaligned_erms` is the standard glibc memcpy function (selected at dynamic link time on CPUs with AVX+ermsb).  *Not* good for reading back from video memory since it's mapped WC.  For that you want SSE4.1 NT loads, as in https://web.archive.org/web/20120210023754/https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/copying-accelerated-video-decode-frame-buffers  Or am I misunderstanding, and this is copying from a MESA buffer, not from actual video RAM?  I'm not familiar with MESA / video-driver internals.

Comment: The Mesa bugtracker is a better place for such issues, and the bug you've opened is already getting very good attention and responses: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/7863